# How do I set HTTP headers using Python's urllib?

Tags: python, http, header, urllib

I am pretty new to Python's [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html).  What I need to do is set a custom HTTP header for the request being sent to the server.

Specifically, I need to set the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) HTTP headers.  I have looked into the Python documentation, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

adding HTTP headers using [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

from the docs:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/')
req.add_header('Referer', 'http://www.python.org/')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = resp.read()
```

Answer (score 138):

For both Python 3 and Python 2, this works:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen  # Python 3
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import Request, urlopen  # Python 2

req = Request('http://api.company.com/items/details?country=US&language=en')
req.add_header('apikey', 'xxx')
content = urlopen(req).read()

print(content)
```

Comment: Can we do the same thing with requests q.add_header('apikey', 'xxx')

Comment: What do you mean, @user3378649?

Comment: @user3378649 may be you means use `requests` python package [custom headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)

Comment: THIS answer - a thousand times YES (thanks!).  I have been struggling for hours trying to find a common interface for python 2 and 3 (between urllib, urllib2 and urllib3).

Answer (score 22):

Use urllib2 and create a Request object which you then hand to urlopen.
http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

I dont really use the "old" urllib anymore.

```
req = urllib2.Request("http://google.com", None, {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

untested....

Answer (score 1):

For multiple headers do as follow:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/')
req.add_header('param1', '212212')
req.add_header('param2', '12345678')
req.add_header('other_param1', 'sample')
req.add_header('other_param2', 'sample1111')
req.add_header('and_any_other_parame', 'testttt')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = resp.read()
```

Comment: Do _not_ do this, simply pass in a headers dictionary if you have multiple header fields to use.

Comment: guess you are right - but hey, this was 2015 for Python 2.7
Theses days - I'm populating a dictionary.