# Run cURL command in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, python-requests, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I need to run

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json+v6" -H "x-api-key: <your_api_key>" \https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests\?registration=ZZ99ABC
```

In Python 2.7. I've looked into using requests but I'm unsure how to structure it specifically for the above command.

Help appreciated

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933546/1409704) - it recommends using `urllib2`, adding the headers you need, as well as reading the response.

Comment: Have you already tried https://curl.trillworks.com to get an idea for using the requests library?

Answer (score 0):

To break down your requirements, you need to:

- Perform a request to a url (to the MOT service)
- Include some headers (the `-H` params to curl)

You can easily do those things using requests:

```
import request

url = "https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests?registration=ZZ99ABC"
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json+v6",
    "x-api-key": "your-key",

}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```