# i am getting python error - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, request

Need some help here. I am trying to send a JWT token with header in my request. When i directly copy paste the token in the request (line 6) its working fine. Where as when i concatenate as string and send (line 3 & 5) it throwing error. But when print the token its having the correct token value.THe error i have pasted below after the code

```
response = requests.post("some URL")
token = response.text
header_content = "{'Authorization': 'Bearer "+token+"'}"
print(header_content)
response = requests.get(url, headers=header_content)
#response = requests.get(url, headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImhjbF9yZXBvcnRpbmcuc2VydmljZWFjY291bnRAc2x1LnRlYW1keW5hbWl4LmNvbSIsInRkeF9lbnRpdHkiOiIyIiwidGR4X3BhcnRpdGlvbiI6IjcwIiwiaXNzIjoiVEQiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy50ZWFtZHluYW1peC5jb20vIiwiZXhwIjoxNjIyOTgyNzg5LCJuYmYiOjE2MjI4OTYzODl9.82FuBtybRBk3Ot-whKYEXw2yFeNXBp566MubEA9G-BE'})

the error i am seeing is

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\PycharmProjects\SLU_DailyReport_Automation\Rest_Testing.py", line 24, in <module>
response = requests.get(url, headers=header_content)
File "C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\PycharmProjects\SLU_DailyReport_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\PycharmProjects\SLU_DailyReport_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\PycharmProjects\SLU_DailyReport_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\PycharmProjects\SLU_DailyReport_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
p.prepare(
File "C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\PycharmProjects\SLU_DailyReport_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 317, in prepare
self.prepare_headers(headers)
File "C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\PycharmProjects\SLU_DailyReport_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 449, in prepare_headers
for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: `headers=` needs to be a dict

Answer (score 3):

`header_content` should be a dictionary not string

Change this

```
header_content = "{'Authorization': 'Bearer "+token+"'}"
```

to

```
header_content = {'Authorization': "Bearer "+token}
```

You can trace that from error Traceback :

```
for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

`.items()` is an attribute for a dictionary `not string` which returns a list of tuple pair :

In your case `header.items()` is

```
[('Authorization', 'Bearer your_token')]
```

Comment: header_content = {'Authorization': 'Bearer "+token+"'}
Not working. token variable is not replacing with values not sure how to solve this

Comment: i made this happen by below  <br/>

          `value = "Bearer "+token
          header_content = {'Authorization': value}
          print(header_content)
          response = requests.get(url, headers=header_content)`
<br/>
This worked

Comment: Yup! my bad, i didn't focused on that part, anyway that's a small fix which you yourself have made it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

the issue here is requests is expecting a dictionary, not a string that resembles a python dictionary. in the 2nd last line of the error messages it shows `for header in headers.items():` which is a python dictionary method. to address this problem u can use json module from python.

```py
import json
header_content = '{"Authorization": "Bearer " + "some_token"}'
header_content = dict(json.loads(header_content)
response = requests.get(url, headers = header_content)
```

Note: for some reason json requires the contents enclosed with `"` instead of `'`.

Comment: hi thanks for your help. But i am appending the token variable in run time with the Authorization: Bearer Token...Not sure how to append. Your code is throwing error 
<error>
raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
</error>

Comment: `'{"Authorization": "Bearer "' + some_token + '}'`

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what framework you use, but usually there is a separate function to add headers, instead of just adding them as a string.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933546/11220643), in Python with urllib2 it would be:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/')
req.add_header('Referer', 'http://www.python.org/')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = resp.read()
```

For node.js with express it is explained in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23759686/11220643)